# FileInputStream fis.read() gives exception

Tags: android

I want to gain access to SD-CARD for this i am write some code :

```
File f=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

//   f=/mnt/sdcard 

byte[] bytearray=new byte[4];

FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(f);

fis.read(bytearray,1,1);   //This line gives exception
```

I  can't figure out why this an exception

Comment: first, post your logcat. second, check if you have valid permissions to read from external storage

Comment: state permission in manifest file with uses-permission tag. Have u done that??

Comment: yes already gave android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to application but still gives exception

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to read is not actually a file, but a directory.

This is the reason why you are getting an exception.

For listing de directectory contents, you should use the `list()` method on the File object.

Comment: I want to read SD card internally, is there any way to do that?

Comment: What do you want to read? a file, any file, listing the SD content? You cannot use the FileInputStream to read a directory. You can list the files inside the dir, and read them one at a time.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not posible in Java. Maybe this could be a new question.